# jQuery.ajax() sends request more than once if headers object is set

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-headers

When I run this, it sends two requests for some reason. When I remove the `headers` object though it only runs once. Why is it running twice with the headers object?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "get",
    headers: {
        Time: time
    },
    url: getHost() + "/leaderboard/top?gameId=" + gameId + "&token=" + createToken([gameId, time]),
    dataType: "json",
    complete: function(data){
        showOutput(JSON.parse(data.responseText));
    }
});
```

When I look in the chrome network inspector, I see that under `Method` one says `GET` and the other says `OPTIONS`. Other than that the request is exactly the same.

On the server I have the following headers set:

```
this.res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/json; charset=utf-8");
this.res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
this.res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Time");
```

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544422/jquery-ajax-executed-twice

Comment: That was the preflight request.

Comment: BTW, you can trigger a non-preflighted request with Content-Type of `text/plain` and not `text/json`.

Comment: check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under certain conditions(in this case the presents of the time header) for cross origin GET request a [pre-flight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Preflighted_requests) OPTIONS request is sent first to make sure that the receiving server accepts these kinds of requests.

Do some reading on Cross Origin Resource Sharing and Same Origin Policy.

Comment: I have updated the question with the server headers that I am using. Are those headers what you are talking about?

Comment: @TheBoogieMan no the headers set in ajax request.